# Is internet tethering possible on Android phone via Bluetooth or Wi-Fi?

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

I have HTC Desire and I use different Wi-Fi networks with it, but I don't have mobile internet access. My laptop is usually connected via a mobile modem.

Is there a way to share the laptop's internet access via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?

Comment: This seems like a question for Super User, as it's about computers and not necessarily about gadgets.

Comment: I think it is suitable for both sites, but I imagine that it would be turned down there as well, because I mention a device specifically and that would be considered device specific question, thus it is out scope there, because the emphasis is on the device and not the PC. :)

Comment: @Kyle: as a Super User mod I would vote for keeping gadget questions here, even if they interface with a computer

Comment: @Ivo If you take away the fact that he wants to use it with his phone, this *isn't a gadget question at all*. This could just as well be one computer sharing its internet via wifi with another computer.

Answer (score 6):

Lorenz Blog has [an article](https://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-share-internet-connection-between-pc-and-android-phone-using-wifi/) which explains how to set up a Wireless Hosted Network specifically on Windows 7.

To do so, the easiest way is to install either [Virtual Router](https://github.com/crpietschmann/VirtualRouter) or [Connectify](https://www.connectify.me/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [londatiga.net](https://londatiga.net/images/wifi/virtual_router.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [londatiga.net](https://londatiga.net/images/wifi/connectify.jpg))</sub>

These programs will set up your computer to pass through the Wi-Fi connection

Then on the Android device:

- Go to Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Wi-Fi Settings
- Open Advance settings menu
- Tick the Use static IP option
- Enter your desired IP address (ex: 192.168.2.2)  into IP Address field
- Enter your IPV4 Address (ex. 192.168.2.1) into Gateway field
- Enter 255.255.255.0 into Netmask field
- Enter your internet connection’s DNS server (use `ipconfig /all` command to get DNS info) into DNS 1 and DNS 2. As an alternative, you can use Google Public DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
- Connect to Wi-Fi using your password
- Disable and Enable Wi-Fi (in case if it won’t connect)
- Check the connection using browser or other application.

Comment: Note these steps may not work on every computer and every Android device. Please vote down if it DOESN'T work for you and mention your setup.

Comment: actually this steps will work if your pc hardware supports connectify. If your android has wifi capability; there is no reason why not to connect to wireless access point.