# Get internet access via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, tethering, bluetooth-tethering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Internet  tethering possible on Android phone via bluetooth or WiFi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/549/is-internet-tethering-possible-on-android-phone-via-bluetooth-or-wifi)
>   [Tethering Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3110) via Nokia E71](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/tethering-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-gt-p3110-via-nokia-e71)

In the era of PDA's most of them could connect to internet by pairing them with internet enabled dumbphones.

I would like to do the same with an android device however I can't seem to find ANY app that would allow me to do that. There's a few that allow you to share the android devices internet access via bluetooth but not the other way around.

Is there an app out there that would allow me to access internet via bluetooth? Is it available natively in some android version? (Device that I have is 2.3.5 and I don't have access to newer versions)

(Maybe someone would like to write one?)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a duplicate. The linked question does ask (offhandedly) about bluetooth, but no one mentions it in any answers. The question here specifically wants to know about bluetooth, so the linked question won't help at all.

Comment: See Mirko's [tether apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Mirko+Solazzi). And also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23571/tethering-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-gt-p3110-via-nokia-e71

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called [reverse-tether](/questions/tagged/reverse-tether) (or "reverse tethering"), the word "reverse" explaining what your question mentions as *the other way around*. *Reverse Tether* is available via WiFi, Bluetooth, and USB -- but in most cases requires your device to be rooted.

You might want to [search the playstore for "reverse tether"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=reverse+tether&c=apps), results are limited (currently 9 apps show up). Also follow the tag-link in the previous paragraph to find other questions. One that certainly matches your request is [Is Internet tethering possible on Android phone via bluetooth or WiFi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/549/is-internet-tethering-possible-on-android-phone-via-bluetooth-or-wifi). Also take a look at the questions mentioned in the "Related" section of this page (on the right-hand, if you're using a desktop browser).

Comment: I have already looked over all the questions with that tag and searched long and wide at google play. Like I said, I found nothing. The only answer that had something was a rooted device command which doesn't do what the author expects.

Comment: As I said: AFAIK reverse tether always requires root. The playstore link in my answer points to the few apps making it possible. There might be other solutions possible (e.g. via command line in a terminal app or via ADB) -- but I know of no solution not involving root. I'll happily learn I'm wrong if somebody presents a solution not requiring root :)